# Laravel Conditionally adding rules, stop one rule if other validation rule is not valid

Tags: php, laravel

How to stop one validation rule if other rule is not succeeded in laravel

I have an input type for date and I have 3 validation rule in there which are:

1. `date`
2. `date_format:m/d/Y`
3. `after:date('m/d/Y)`.

When I enter an invalid data like `04/05/2014dsada` the after date rule is still running. How can I stop running the after validation rule?

How to finish this in Laravel??

Here's my sample code:

```
$rules = array('mmad_starting_date' => 'date|required|date_format:m/d/Y|after:'.date("m/d/Y H:i"));
```

if i will use laravel Conditionally Adding Rules.

```
$validator->sometimes('mmad_starting_date', 'after:'.date(m/d/Y), function($input){
       //how can i check if the mad_starting_date is a valid date
     return $input->mmad_starting_date = (what should i input here);
});
```

Comment: Hi! You are gonna have to add some of your code, use the edit button and paste in your code.

Comment: Please add some code samples that you used. We don't currently know what you need to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: (basically the content of the `date_format` rule...)

```
$validator->sometimes('mmad_starting_date', 'after:'.date(m/d/Y), function($input){
     $parsed = date_parse_from_format('m/d/Y', $input->mmad_starting_date);
     return $parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0;
 });
```

Comment: Sorry I was wrong Laravel will not stop executing other rules. However the real question is, why do you want it to do that?

Comment: i think its not appropriate to run the after validation rule if the user inputted an wrong data like what i provided above ie. the user inputed the correct date but at the end of the date he entered inappropriate information like 04/04/2015oiewq.

Comment: in short if the user inputed a wrong date the ``after`` validation rule should not be run.

Comment: I understood your question. But what difference does it make for you if it runs or not?

Comment: There's really no big difference i just wanna know if its possible.

Comment: It's not possible. (except if you would run the validator twice with different rules). It might be interesting to implement this in the validator though. Would you have a good idea how the usage could look like?

Comment: If you have a good idea how the validator could be used to stop after failing, I'd implement it and make a pull request. With some luck it would be merged into the core and everybody could use it. But I have no idea how this "option" could be set. One (bad) way would be something like: `$validator Validator::make(...); $validator->abortAfterFailure(true);`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid passing on to next rule for an attribute if earlier one has already failed.

Just extend the Illuminate\Validation\Validator class and override the passes method.

Break the loop as soon as you encounter error in MessageBag for that attribute.

```
public function passes()
{
    $this->messages = new MessageBag;

    // We'll spin through each rule, validating the attributes attached to that
    // rule. Any error messages will be added to the containers with each of
    // the other error messages, returning true if we don't have messages.
    foreach ($this->rules as $attribute => $rules)
    {
        foreach ($rules as $rule)
        {
            $this->validate($attribute, $rule);
            /* If the error MessageBag has error for the $attribute, break */
            if($this->messages->has($attribute))
                break;
        }
    }

    // Here we will spin through all of the "after" hooks on this validator and
    // fire them off. This gives the callbacks a chance to perform all kinds
    // of other validation that needs to get wrapped up in this operation.
    foreach ($this->after as $after)
    {
        call_user_func($after);
    }

    return count($this->messages->all()) === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2 you can do that easily by adding `bail` rule. If you add `bail` rule to an attribute, validation will not check other rules if one rule fail.

In your case you can simply use,

```
$rules = array('mmad_starting_date' => 'bail|required|date_format:m/d/Y|after:'.date("m/d/Y H:i"));
```

Refer Laravel validation doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation).

Comment: Just tested this for manual validation - Validator::make() method. It looks, Laravel 5.2 ignores bail rule completely.

Answer (score 0):

Thnx lukasgeiter your solutions worked,

what i did also is create a custom validator in my corevalidator class and create two functions and it works.

```
 public function validateAfterDatetoday($attribute, $value, $parameters){

    $today = new DateTime(date("m/d/Y H:i"));

    if($this->validateThisDate($value)){
        $date = new DateTime($value);

        if($today > $date){
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}
 function validateThisDate($date){

    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);

    if($d){

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and use it in my mmad_starting_date field. anyways your solution is better.